# best pratice to compile all templates files in a unique file with backbone/marionette

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, underscore.js, marionette, underscore.js-templating

I have a huge application built with Backbone, Marionette, Require.js and this is an example of the view that I'm using:

```
define([
 'backbone',
 'text!templates/oauth.html'
], function (Backbone, Template) {
var OAuthView = Backbone.View.extend({

    template: _.template(Template),
    render: function() {

        var type = this.options.error;
        this.$el.html(this.template({ error: type }));

        return this;
    }


});

return OAuthView;
```

});

I would like to have in production (only in production because in development I like that all template files are separated) a single file html and use this
https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.templatecache.md to improve the performance.

Any hints/idea? How can you solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what your workflow is, I offer this as a solution that works for me. 
I use [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) as my automation tool, and the 
[grunt jst plugin](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jst) to automate
the pre-compilation of all my templates.

This creates a single javascript file will all the compiled templates.
Once include this file in your html document you can reference all
templates through the `window.JST[...]` object.

---

I keep all my templates in `src/templates/views/*` and `src/templates/layouts/*`.

My jst config looks likes this:

```
jst: {
  compile: {
    options: {
      prettify: false,
      amdWrapper: false,
      processName: function (filename) {
        var key = 'templates/';
        // src/templates/views/viewName.js -> views/viewName
        return filename.slice(filename.indexOf(key) + key.length, filename.lastIndexOf('.'));
      }
    },
    files: {
      "<%= app.src %>/scripts/templates.js": ["<%= app.src %>/**/*.tpl"]
    }
  }
},
```

This gives me a `src/scripts/templates.js` file looking like this:

```
this["JST"] = this["JST"] || {};

this["JST"]["views/modal"] = function(obj) {
    // compiled template here...
};
...
```

And finally my views look like this:

```
var ModalView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: window.JST['views/modal'],
    ...
});
```

You can easily wrap `window.JST['views/modal']` in a helper, much like `Marionette.TemplateCache`. Perhaps this is where you could handle dev/production differences, dynamically requiring the template if in dev, loading the pre-compiled version for production.

---

Ideally you want to abstract the logic for getting a template into a function.

In development you could have something like this where you require all your
templates and based on the input name you return the correct template. You'll have to adjust this depending upon how your app/workflow is designed.

```
define([
    'text!templates/oauth.html',
    'text!templates/otherTemplate.html',
    ...
], function () {
    App.getTemplate = function (name) {
        return require('text!templates/' + name + '.html');
    };
});
```

Then in production you would include this alternate version of the `getTemplate`
function that access the precompiled templates

```
App.getTemplate = function (name) {
    return window.JST[name];
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint man! Acctually I solved partially.
Now I'm able to collect all the template in a single file and use it in my view: http://dpaste.com/hold/1682144/ and it works!

Now I want to use window.JST['about']() ONLY when I'm in production, and define(['text!templates/login.html'], function (template) { //use template  });

when I'm in development mode. How you would design it? Thanks again.

Comment: @beddamadre I added a note about this at the bottom of my answer. Hopefully it offers some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Solved using https://github.com/guybedford/require-is – any feedback?

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'app',
    'marionette',
    'is!dev?text!templates/about.html'
], function ($, app, Marionette, template) {
    var AboutView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({

        getTemplate: function () {
            if(template){
                return template;
            }else{
                return window.JST['about']();
            }
        },

        render: function() {
            this.$el.html(_.template(this.getTemplate()));
            return this;
        }

    });

    return AboutView;
});
```

It could be cool to add getTemplate directly on the base backbone or marionette view.